# How to configure merge commit template on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to configure merge commit template on Azure DevOps?
I would like to for example to Azure add Pull Request link to merge commit when I'm completing Pull Request.

EDIT:
when I'm completing Pull Request then Azure DevOps shows window `Complete pull request` like on the picture. Azure DevOps automatically add line `Related work items: #29272156` and I would like to Azure DevOps add also link to completed pull request.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pull request templates: [Improve pull request descriptions using templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-request-templates?view=azure-devops). All information from the pull request description will be moved to the commit description.

A link to a source pull request you can find in the details tab of your commit:

[image]

Additionally, you can find this info in Visual Studio:

[image]

Comment: I think it's not what I'm looking for. As I understand I can't define there adding Pull Request link to commit description.

Comment: @DawidKrok The commit details tab contains information about source pull requests.

Comment: I would like to be able to see this link when I'm using command `git log` or when I'm using some local installed tool for manage git and then click in link and open Pull Request page for see details of review

Comment: @DawidKrok Visual Studio supports the viewing PRs in history. Or can try to use rest API to update the description of your PRs through validation builds: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1.